# better word for single handedly

Tags: meaning

I was wondering if I want to say "No news, single-handedly / on it's own, is good news" is there any better way to say it?

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: The expression _no news is good news_ seems appropriate here.

Comment: You are looking for "in and of itself". But what you are *really* looking for is dropping the word altogether because you already have "on its own" in there which means the same thing. (What you are not looking for, but should be looking for, is a dictionary that explains the difference between *its* and *it's*.) So: no news on its own is good news. No news by itself is good news. No news in and of itself is good news. This is not rocket science. Lastly, please do not create a second account to provide non-answers to your own questions. Thank you.

Comment: @Reg Dwight Excellent suggestion. And excellent detective work. Multiple identity fraud can really mess up the works. There should be automatic fines.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I get it, you understand better than us, no need to be rude about it! And as far as my knowledge goes, there's no dictionary that explains the difference between "it's" and "its" (by the way it was a typo same as  "What you are now looking for" and "What you are not looking for"). And as for your detective work, this question was a discussion between 2 colleges in a work place, and the answer you're referring to is made by him to complete the question I asked. And finally, yeah, right, you know English better than me, give yourself a pat on the back

Answer (score 1):

You could use the expression ***by itself***

Answer (score 0):

How about "**in isolation**"?

"Single-handedly" here makes no sense, actually.